# What happened to my Power Armor?

Tags: fallout-4

I hadn't had any fusion cores and I prefer sneak/sniper build during this (my first of F4) run so after defeating the first Deathclaw, I just left it there. Now that I'm supposed to find Virgil in the Glowing Sea, I cannot find it anywhere in <strike>Lexington</strike> Concord (I checked the museum Vertibird in case it respawned there). What happened to it (did Brotherhood of Steel reclaim it?) How can I prevent it from happening again? I am using a spare one I found during The Big Dig, but I'd like to not lose this one.

Comment: Have you checked Sanctuary if it is there? It is also possible that an NPC takes the armor if there is still a power core in it.

Comment: If you're heading to the glowing sea you will find many other sets of power armor on the way down there. There's pretty much zero threat of never being able to find one or construct one easily. The one you find during the first death claw is a low level one anyhow. I keep them on a power armor station in any settlement and they never vanish on me

Comment: Your map has an icon for your last used Power Armor.  You should always have one displayed.

Comment: @Tom No, PA icon was not over Sanctuary (I checked when I was looking for it in Concord).

Answer (score 11):

Power Armor is only taken by NPCs if there's a Fusion Core left inside of it with more than 0% juice. NPCs won't put Fusion Cores into unpowered Power Armor suits or frames, so if you left it somewhere without one, it will still be exactly where you left it, though if you decide to use a different Power Armor set, then the map will no longer display the old one, as only the most recently used set will be marked on the map.

That said, I noticed you said you've searched Lexington, however, the first Power Armor you find and most likely used to beat that Deathclaw, is actually in **Concord**. If you haven't checked that town, then that might be where it actually is.

---

If you are positive there was not even a 1% Fusion Core in the Power Armor you previously ditched, then it is still exactly where it was taken off, you may just need to look around, as you may have taken it off somewhere other than where you thought you did.

If you *did* leave a Fusion Core in there, then you might as well just move on. By now, its probably gone, and even if you manage to find the frame somewhere, it's very possible that whoever equipped it got into a fight somewhere along the way and had the armor pieces break off.

Answer (score 2):

One of two things could've happened here:

- Power Armor automatically despawns if left alone for too long.
- An NPC "stole" the Power Armor. Usually done during combat situations, so a Raider or a Minutemen could've taken them. This only happens because if left a Power Core in it tho.

To make sure this doesn't happen again, do not leave your power armor for an extended period of time. That's really the only thing you can do.

Comment: I don't think this is quite right. My first save file has over two weeks real time logged and I've never had a single Power Armor frame (and I have 12+) despawn on me. I think the real issue is that OP is looking in the wrong town

Comment: Also, if you're going to leave the armor at all, make sure to pull the Core.

Comment: @Vemonus I heard that already, but I'm fairly sure they do despawn. I lost several power armors to the oblivion, for example once in the in the national guard training yard. I walked in with a power armor, killed the ghoul, switched power armors because I thought the new one was fancy as hell, ported into a settlement and forgot about the one. A few hours later, I remembered and wanted to get it back, but it was gone, and I'm fairly sure no NPC walked in there. Also, I did lose ~3 other suits of power armor on other occasions. So, uhm, I'm fairly sure they DO despawn und certain circumstances.

Comment: @Vemonus I wrote wrong town as I fast traveled to museum.

Comment: @YUNOWORK I have left close to 10 Power Armor in Sanctuary, without them despawning. Are you absolutely sure they do despawn? Do you have any sources confirming this? In the cases where your armors disappeared, are you sure you had removed the Power Core from the armor?

Comment: Like Laf I also had a collection of power armors (without a core in it) in Sanctuary none of them ever disappeared.

Comment: @Laf I'm dead sure. I never leave a core inside my power armors when leaving to prevent NPCs from taking it. You made me unsure myself, so I googled for the last hour and the internet is full of opposite opinions. Some say they do despawn, some say they don't. I guess we will never know for sure. I DO know that I did lose a few sets of power armor which have not been stolen (no Power Core). Maybe - just maybe - it's a bug, which would mean I've spread wrong information for the past 2 years. But I want that proven before I believe it.^^

Comment: @YUNOWORK wouldn't be the first time Bethesda left a bug in the game, I wouldn't be surprised ;)

Comment: You don't have to leave power cores in the armor.  Some NPCs can pick them up and use the power armors.

One of my games I've had over 50 power armor frames.  I started collecting BoS frames by shooting out the cores.  I had the opposite problem... I can't get my villagers to stay in the PA...

Comment: If you leave power armor in a settlement it will not despawn.  It may be used by an NPC or settler though if it has a fusion core.  If you leave it outside a settlement it will despawn (dont know how long it takes to do so).  Always take the parts with you if you are leaving the power armor outside a settlement.